# 401.2 IIS Error using Anonymous Authentication

Tags: iis

I have set-up my Windows 10 Home PC as a web server to do some development work. I need to use Anonymous Authentication but I'm having issues with 401.2 errors.

[401.2 Error](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9uv28Z16v77cGVZQm42bmhubEE)

The IIS log gives me:

**2015-11-01 18:29:12 192.168.1.14 GET /temp/index.html - 80 - 192.168.1.14 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/46.0.2490.80+Safari/537.36 - 401 2 5 0"**

It's a simple index.html page containing just "Hello World!

I've been through the MS troubleshooting article here but it doesn't help support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/907273

I have posted the IIS set-up, folder set-up, Access control list on the folder and  the AppPool Settings:

[Link to settings](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B9uv28Z16v77cGpfbUp2ZnJZcTA&usp=sharing)

Thanks

Jeff

Comment: So I gave up on trying to resolve this. I ended up uninstalling all IIS features and re-installing from scratch. After re-installing Anonymous Authentication now works!! :-) If turning it off and turning it back on again doesn't work then try uninstalling and reinstalling! IT support at its best!!

Comment: I had this issue too. I solved it by making sure that there was an "allow" rule under Authorization Rules -  for all users. Previously there was nothing there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I gave up on trying to resolve this. I ended up uninstalling all IIS features and re-installing from scratch. After re-installing Anonymous Authentication now works!! :-) If turning it off and turning it back on again doesn't work then try uninstalling and reinstalling! IT support at its best!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and struggled for couple of days. Finally figured it out that one of the reason to get the `401.2` error was because Authentication modules were not installed.

Make sure you have your desired Authentication modules(i.e. Anonymous Authentication) installed in IIS.

**To verify go to IIS Manager -> Select root -> Select Authentication.**

[image]

[image]

**If it's not showing your Authentication type then go to control panel -> Add/Remove program or goto Run -> type "appwiz.cpl" -> enter to open the add remove program wizard.**

[image]

**Go to `windows features` -> IIS -> Authentication**

[image]

> **Note:** If you only want to fix this error in Visual studio for development purpose then you don't need to install those modules. In case you're using IIS express simply go to project properties by pressing **"F4"** and change the Authentication type from there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply vendettamit. As you can see from my screen shots Anonymous authentication is already installed by default in IIS and is selected as the ONLY enabled authentication type for this application. I wonder is this a limitation in Windows 10 Home?